# Search in a dataframe using a list of terms and add a new column with the term/s founded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe and a list of terms like this:

```
ID          COUNTRY     TEXT
123432      FR          En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero 
123321      DE          No ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero
324221      UK          Tenía en su casa una ama que pasaba de los cuarenta, y una sobrina que no llegaba a los veinte
343212      IT          Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años
431234      ES          Es, pues, de saber que este sobredicho hidalgo, los ratos que estaba ocioso -que eran los más del año-, se daba a leer libros de caballerías
123213      AU          Pero esto importa poco a nuestro cuento: basta que en la narración dél no se salga un punto de la verdad.
```

```
list_of_terms = ['hidalgo', 'años', 'Mancha' ]
```

The **list_of_terms** is quite bigger, so, I need a loop to access to all the strings inside the list.

What I want to obtain is a new dataframe with the rows that contain the list of terms and a New Column Called **KEYWORDS** with the keyword/keywords located inside the column TEXT.

The resulting dataframe would be:

```
ID          COUNTRY    KEYWORDS           TEXT
123432      FR         'Mancha'           En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero 
123321      DE         'hidalgo'          No ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero
343212      IT         'hidalgo','años'   Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años
431234      ES         'hidalgo'          Es, pues, de saber que este sobredicho hidalgo, los ratos que estaba ocioso -que eran los más del año-, se daba a leer libros de caballerías
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering your dataframe as pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['123432','123321','324221','343212','431234','123213'],
                   'COUNTRY': ['FR', 'DE', 'UK', 'IT', 'ES', 'AU'],
                   'TEXT':['En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero ', 'No ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero','Tenía en su casa una ama que pasaba de los cuarenta, y una sobrina que no llegaba a los veinte', 'Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años', 'Es, pues, de saber que este sobredicho hidalgo, los ratos que estaba ocioso -que eran los más del año-, se daba a leer libros de caballerías','']})

df['KEYWORDS'] = df.apply(lambda row: [el for el in list_of_terms if re.findall("\\b{}\\b".format(el),row.TEXT] , axis=1)
df['KEYWORDS']= df.KEYWORDS.apply(lambda row : np.nan if len(row)==0 else row)
df.dropna(subset=['KEYWORDS'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: It works well, but I need the exact match. For example, the word 'cumpleaños' includes the term 'años'.  In your code this works, but this is not what I want.

I need Only that find a match when the word años appears without prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: @Marc Edited the solution, let me if you face any issue. Here I have used regex to the if condition.

Comment: It doesn't work yet although it seems that regex is the solution.
The error now is the following:

```error: ('unterminated character set at position 2', 'occurred at index 0')```

Looking at my keywords, some of them has special characters like '[]', ' ; ' or '<'. Those characters could be removed from the string. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Can you put the exact input of TEXT, with what you are testing? This can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and a [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to aggregate with a `join`:

```
r = r'({})'.format('|'.join(list_of_terms))
# '(hidalgo|años|Mancha)'
df['KEYWORDS'] = (df.TEXT.str.extractall(r)
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .agg(', '.join))
df[df.KEYWORDS.notna()]

ID COUNTRY                                               TEXT  \
0  123432      FR  En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no qu...   
1  123321      DE  No ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los...   
3  343212      IT  Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cin...   
4  431234      ES  Es, pues, de saber que este sobredicho hidalgo...   

        KEYWORDS  
0         Mancha  
1        hidalgo  
3  hidalgo, años  
4        hidalgo
```

Comment: It returns me the following error:

```error: unterminated character set at position 6893```